# NodeJs Passport package compatibility with Linux

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am following this official documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport for passport package.

I am trying to figure out whether this package is compatible with linux or not.

Can anyone help as I am not able to find any other documentation which mentions about its compatibility with other OS.

Note: We are using Passport-0.4.0 version

Comment: first of all passport package has nothing to do with Linux, its just a authentication middleware written in javascript. Nodejs works on Linux thus it can execute javascript & packges like passport. So whats the point of asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it's compatible with Linux.

You can find the official documentation for passport js here: 
https://www.passportjs.org/

Comment: Can you please guide me where I can find in this documentation , that it is compatible with linux?